# Do I need to move local index after table moved to different tablespace

Tags: sql, database, indexing, oracle11g, ddl

I am little confused about moving a table to different tablespace when it has couple of indexes which are local indexes, I suppose this means that the indexes are stored in some tablespace same as owner table, so when I moved the table to different tablespace then the local indexes are moved too then I just need to rebuild them wothout specifying the tablespace.

I mean

```
ALTER INDEX XXX REBUILD;
```

instead of

```
ALTER INDEX XXX REBUILD TABLESPACE XX;
```

Am I right or I am missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining an index as `local` has nothing to do with the tablespace it's stored on. `local` refers to partitioned indexes being partitioned in the same way the table they refer to is, as opposed to a `global` partitioned index which has its own partitioning definition (or even defined as nonpartitioned), regardless of the table's partitioning.

As you noted, after moving a table you have to rebuild its indexes, but this can be done to any tablespace regardless of the index's `local` or `global` definitions. By default, if a storage clause is not given, the index will be rebuilt on the tablespace it's already stored on.